# WordPress forum plugin that can integrate existing comments

Tags: wordpress, forum

I have a WordPress website that has hundreds of both post and page comments. I'm looking to arrange these, with their relevan post or pages, into a more user-friendly form.

I looked at turning the comments into a forum with [bbPress](https://bbpress.org/). With the "bbPress Topics for Posts" plugin I was able to get all the post comments into the forum. Unfortunately there are 2 major drawbacks that I can see:

- Firstly I can't seem to integrate the Page comments - only the post comments are integrated.
- And secondly, it does not have the ease of use for customers that the WP comments system has - it requires the user to "register" to be able to post. As about 50% of our comments are customer feedback this is not a good option - it's hard enough getting them to leave feedback, and adding a "register" step makes it even harder. The only other option I see is to allow anyone to post to the forum without moderation. This isn't useful either as it opens the door to spam.

So, in brief I am looking for a plugin that can do the following:

- Integrate all existing comments (both posts and pages).
- Allow users to comment without having to register or login (but have all new comments go into a moderation queue before going live - just as in WordPress comments).
- Make the comments/forum simple to navigate so users can easily find answers to their questions.

Does anyone know of a way to get bbPress to do this, or plugin (or set of plugins) that can help me achieve this end?